# TripleDES encrypting with vb.net and decrypting with java

Tags: java, vb.net, encryption, tripledes

I'm creating an interface for two applications that will communicate using encrypted text in .txt files. vb.net app will encrypt and java will decrypt.

vb code

---

```
        Dim nget As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(sInputFilename)
        Dim textBytes As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(nget)

        Dim Passphrase As String = sKey
        Dim UTF8 As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()


        Dim HashProvider As New MD5CryptoServiceProvider()
        Dim TDESKey As Byte() = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase))

        Dim TDESAlgorithm As New TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()

        TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey
        TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB
        TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7

        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Dim encStream As New CryptoStream(ms, TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write)
        encStream.Write(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length)
        encStream.FlushFinalBlock()


        Dim strSave As String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())

        My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(sOutputFilename, strSave, False)
```

---

java code

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String codedtext = null;
        try {
            codedtext = readFile("ect.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);                
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        String decodedtext = null;
        try {
            decodedtext = _decrypt(codedtext,"abcdefgh");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

}

private static String readFile(String path, Charset encoding) 
          throws IOException 
        {
          byte[] encoded = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path));
          return new String(encoded, encoding);
        }

private static String _encrypt(String message, String secretKey) throws Exception {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] plainTextBytes = message.getBytes("utf-8");
    byte[] buf = cipher.doFinal(plainTextBytes);
    byte [] base64Bytes = Base64.encodeBase64(buf);
    String base64EncryptedString = new String(base64Bytes);

    return base64EncryptedString;
}
```

private static String _decrypt(String encryptedText, String secretKey) throws Exception {

```
    byte[] message = Base64.decodeBase64(encryptedText.getBytes("utf-8"));
    //byte[] message = encryptedText.getBytes("utf-8");

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    byte[] digestOfPassword = md.digest(secretKey.getBytes("utf-8"));
    byte[] keyBytes = Arrays.copyOf(digestOfPassword, 24);
    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, "DESede");

    //Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede");
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);

    byte[] plainText = decipher.doFinal(message);

    return new String(plainText, "UTF-8");
}
```

but I'm getting the error

```
at java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -17
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.isBase64(Base64.java:137)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.discardNonBase64(Base64.java:478)
at org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.java:374)
at Test.MyDec._decrypt(MyDec.java:74)
at Test.MyDec.main(MyDec.java:33)
```

when decoding from base64

Comment: I think we need `_decrypt` method as well, and include the line that generates the exception.

Comment: I've added the _decrypt function